# Android Importing Raw JSON into Database without a lot of coding

Tags: android, json, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a sql lite database in my android project that gets fed its data from a web service giving JSON.  The JSON is straight forward, no tags.  It simply has the rows of table data in the same field order as the table in the database.

```
JSON
[["123","ny","45"],
["456","nj","76"],
["778","ca","33"]]
```

SQL Lite Customer Table   CustomerID,State,NumofItems

How can I import this into the database without the overhead  of creating classes for each table etc..  some tables have over 50 fields.

I am using Xamarin if it somehow makes things easier

Comment: Use Realm database instead of sqlite

Comment: Use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) instead of sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon what you mean by `without a lot of coding` and how many rows you are populating ;-)

Using `dynamics` and `Json.Net` you can use `DeserializeObject` to obtain an array of dynamics and loop through those array elements and construct a SQL Insert statement bypassing column names and class/model definitions of each table... Using `dynamics` is slower but unless you are populating a hundred thousand rows every import/app launch/.... this works fine...

This is how I am populating a bunch of tables in a case very much like yours to import numeric sequences for drawing SparkLines within RecyclerView/CardViews, I removed the error checking to simplify the answer:

```
Batteries_V2.Init();
var sqlConn = new SQLiteConnection("foobar.db");
sqlConn.CreateCommand("create table Customer (CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, State TEXT NOT NULL, NumofItems INT NOT NULL)").ExecuteNonQuery();

var jsonString = @"
    [[""123"",""ny"",""45""],
    [""456"",""nj"",""76""],
    [""778"",""ca"",""33""]]"
    ;
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

sqlConn.BeginTransaction();
foreach (var item in jsonResponse)
{
    string aBunchOfValues = "";
    var noOfColumns = item.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
    {
        var isString = !((string)item[i]).TryParse(out float n);
        aBunchOfValues += $"{(isString ? '"' : ' ')}{item[i]}{(isString ? '"' : ' ')} {(i < noOfColumns - 1 ? ',' : ' ')}";
    }
    var sqlInsertString = $"INSERT INTO Customer VALUES ({aBunchOfValues});";
    sqlConn.CreateCommand(sqlInsertString).ExecuteNonQuery();
}
sqlConn.Commit();
```

Note: This is using FKrueger's `sqlite-net` to provide the `SQLiteConnection`, `CreateCommand` and the transaction, this is on top of ESink's `SQLitePCL.raw`, adjust accordingly...

Comment: Do I need this sqlite-net and SQLitePCL in my Xamarin android project for  this function to work?

Comment: @kaielx As the code is written in my example: yes. You have to add a native provider for SQLite anyway since starting in Android N you can not link to the OS provided one, I personally like using `sqlite-net` for my Sqlite ORM needs, but everyone has their own preferences....

Comment: Well this is being developed for Android 4.4 and 5.0 for Enterprise Devices which will never get to Android N.  Will your for loop stand on its own without the  sqlite-net and PCL

Comment: @kaielx Yes, the "loop" is just creating SQL INSERT statements from dynamics created via deserialized Json, how you execute them against your DB is your choice.

Comment: Last Question on this code, I am getting errors on the IsString and TryParse, States there is no Tryparse for String objects and cannot turn object into boolean for the isString.  Doing this in C# Xamarin, am I missing a reference?

Comment: ah... that `TryParse` comes from `ValueTypeHelper`, add that static class/extension to your project and you can use TryParse on strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26138217/4984832

Comment: okay we're getting there,  still does not like the isString and the part of the tryparse  "float" and "n" both throw errors.

Comment: `errors`? What errors? compile errors, runtime exceptions/errors, ?

Comment: 1. cannot turn object into boolean for the "isString"                                                2. "float" invalid expression                                                                                  3. "n" the name n does not exist in the current context

Comment: @kaielx That line is in C# 7 syntax, you must still be using C# 6 compiler, change the `out` parameter to the older syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: Awesome all working, I don't have enough credit to chat, but saw on your profile you offer development.  I am in need of someone to help on this project. Could you reach out to me kaielx@gmail.com